# How to remote install Ubuntu on a server?

Tags: ubuntu-server, remote-installation

I currently have a server powered by `Ubuntu 10.10` at my ISP. It is a custom `RAID5` installation. I want to use `RAID10`, after that I want to re-install everything.
I only have `SSH` access to to the machine. I want to re-install `Ubuntu`. How can I do this on my own?

I've already done something similar with `CentOS`. I had `VNC` access to the graphic installer. It was great.

What can I do this time?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. As far as I know.
You need "real" remote access to your server. By that I mean KVM over IP for example.
Something that would make you access the server like you would physically.